# Errors loading loosely linked user assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-assembly

Good morning.

I am developing a Web API using Net 6.

The preliminary structure of the API is shown in the figure.

[image]

**ContractGpdApi** - this is the direct assembly of the API. It has a reference to the ContractGpdApi.ServiceInterfaces assembly.
**ContractGpdApi.ServiceInterfaces** - this assembly containing the DTO classes (business models) and service interfaces.
**ContractGpdApi.ServiceImplementations** - this assembly contains classes that implement the ContractGpdApi.ServiceInterfaces assembly interfaces. The assembly adapts the methods and classes of the ContractGpdApi.DbServiceInterfaces assembly into the methods and classes of the ContractGpdApi.ServiceInterfaces assembly.
**ContractGpdApi.DbServiceInterfaces** - this assembly contains classes and database access layer interfaces.
**ContractGpdApi.DbServiceImplementations** - this assembly contains classes that implement the ContractGpdApi.DbServiceInterfaces assembly interfaces. The assembly contains a reference to the ContractGpdApi.DbServiceInterfaces assembly, as well as references to the microsoft.entityframeworkcore, microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver assemblies

I ended up implementing the Ladder pattern and dividing the CUI into loosely coupled layers.

The **DB layer** is represented by two assemblies: ContractGpdApi.DbServiceImplementations and ContractGpdApi.DbServiceInterfaces.

The **business work layer** is represented by two assemblies: ContractGpdApi.ServiceImplementations and ContractGpdApi.ServiceInterfaces.

Accordingly, assembly ContractGpdApi will be a kind of root where you load and embed dependencies, loosely linked assemblies.

The following errors occur when loading assemblies:

1. Could not load file or assembly 'ContractGpdApi.DbServiceInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The specified file cannot be found.
2. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The specified file cannot be found.

[image]

All other assemblies are loaded normally.
Contents of the ContractGpdApi.csproj file:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ContractGpdApi.ServiceInterfaces\ContractGpdApi.ServiceInterfaces.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="call F:\CopyingAssemblies.bat" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Contents of the CopyingAssemblies.bat file:

```
xcopy /y "C:\Git\ContractGpdApi\ContractGpdApi.DbServiceImplementations\bin\Debug\net6.0\*.dll" "C:\Git\ContractGpdApi\ContractGpdApi\bin\Debug\net6.0"
xcopy /y "C:\Git\ContractGpdApi\ContractGpdApi.ServiceImplementations\bin\Debug\net6.0\*.dll" "C:\Git\ContractGpdApi\ContractGpdApi\bin\Debug\net6.0"
```

**Tell me, what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You may want to use `.net-assembly` tag instead of `assembly`. Do read the description of `assembly` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a change to the method code:

```
 private static Assembly LoadAssembly(string assemblyName, bool skipOnError)
    {
        try
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName); //Old code: Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (!(skipOnError && (e is FileNotFoundException || e is FileLoadException || e is BadImageFormatException)))
            {
                throw;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This edit fixed only the first error:

Could not load file or assembly 'ContractGpdApi.DbServiceInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The specified file cannot be found.